# Why I get an error when I try to deploy a react app to GitHub Pages?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to deploy a react app to GitHub pages...

Commands on package.json:

```
 "predeploy": "npm run build",
 "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

and received this error:

```
The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

It was supposed to deploy.

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit short and lacks some context. You'll be more likely to get an answer if you ask it in the format "here's what I did, here's what I expected, here's what actually happened" - currently, we only have the last part. For example, which command did you run, what does your config files if any look like, etc. And ideally, try to reduce it to the smallest possible case by removing stuff from your code that is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved mine. Newer version 2.1 has some issue. Revert back to 2.0.1.

- Reinstall Github pages with a specific version:

```
npm uninstall gh-pages

npm i gh-pages@2.0.1

npm run deploy // as usual
```

Hope that helped. :)